# Convert large httppostedfilebase to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, out-of-memory

I want to convert httppostedfilebase type to byte[] type.
I use this code :

```
    private static byte[] ConverToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength; //134675091 (129MB)
        MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);//System.OutOfMemoryException
        byte[] data = target.ToArray();

        return data;
    }
```

When I use this code, I get the `System.OutOfMemoryException.`

any soulotion about it

Comment: You could try `MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream(file.ContentLength);` but worst case it will blow up on that line, instead of your CopyTo if your system is under memory pressure.

Comment: I get the System.OutOfMemoryException when i use `MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream(file.ContentLength);`

Comment: Nobody has any idea?

Comment: No, with so little to go on, it is impossible to say where all your memory went causing it just at this particular call to run out of memory. Google for similar issues, and then you  would find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758975/asp-net-mvc-site-running-out-of-memory as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may creating more than one copy of byte stream with `MemoryStream`, this is why `OutOfMemoryException` was thrown. Use `BinaryReader` instead:

```
private static byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
    byte[] data = null;
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        data = br.ReadBytes(fileSizeInBytes);
    }

    return data;
}
```

NB: I strongly suggests `using` statement wraps all instance creation which uses memory space and implements `IDisposable` such like `MemoryStream` does.

Similar issue:

[Convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[] array](https://forums.asp.net/t/2130699.aspx?Convert%20HttpPostedFileBase%20to%20byte%20Exception_WasThrown)

Comment: Thank you, But it not work for me.
`data = br.ReadBytes(fileSizeInBytes);` throw System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: What kind of 'not working'? Is the same exception thrown again or something else happens?

Comment: I get System.OutOfMemoryException again!